# pmset: Error 0xe00002bc

Tags: macos, command-line, sleep-wake, shutdown, pmset

I've recently started getting this error when running any of these commands on my iMac (macOS Ventura 13.5.2 (22G91)):

```
sudo pmset sched cancelall
pmset: Error 0xe00002bc scheduling repeating events

sudo pmset repeat shutdown MTWRFSU 01:00:00
pmset: Error 0xe00002bc cancelling all scheduled events
```

Interestingly, I've noticed that I can switch between sleep/shutdown but I can't cancel:

```
sudo pmset repeat shutdown MTWRFSU 01:00:00
pmset: Error 0xe00002bc scheduling repeating events

pmset -g sched
Repeating power events:
  shutdown at 1:00AM every day
# error, but shutdown is set 

sudo pmset repeat sleep MTWRFSU 01:00:00
pmset: Error 0xe00002bc scheduling repeating events

pmset -g sched
Repeating power events:
  sleep at 1:00AM every day
# error, but it switched to sleep 

sudo pmset sched cancelall
pmset: Error 0xe00002bc cancelling all scheduled events
pmset -g sched
Repeating power events:
  sleep at 1:00AM every day

# cancelling doesn't work
```

I've searched everywhere without luck. I don't see any relevant info on my `/var/log/system.log` and I've tried resetting the SMC, but the issue remains. Any ideas?

Here's the output of my `pmset -g assertions` in case it's useful:

```
pmset -g assertions
2023-09-09 10:30:37 +0200
Assertion status system-wide:
   BackgroundTask                 1
   ApplePushServiceTask           0
   UserIsActive                   1
   PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep    0
   PreventSystemSleep             0
   ExternalMedia                  1
   PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     1
   NetworkClientActive            0
Listed by owning process:
   pid 156(bluetoothd): [0x0000081e0001885b] 00:00:20 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "com.apple.BTStack"
   pid 745(sharingd): [0x0000061c000187e3] 00:08:54 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "Handoff"
   pid 300(backupd): [0x00000188000185cd] 00:28:25 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "Backup Job"
   pid 448(mdsync): [0x000005ab000b87d8] 00:10:46 BackgroundTask named: "com.apple.metadata.mds.scan"
   pid 106(powerd): [0x0000002b0008812b] 00:34:15 ExternalMedia named: "com.apple.powermanagement.externalmediamounted"
   pid 162(WindowServer): [0x00000065000981a8] 00:00:00 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle serviceID:100000b78 service:AppleUserHIDEventService product:Karabiner DriverKit VirtualHIDKeyboard 1.6.0 eventType:3"
    Timeout will fire in 300 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
   pid 349(mds_stores): [0x00000039000b816a] 00:34:01 BackgroundTask named: "com.apple.metadata.mds_stores.power"
   pid 121(mds): [0x0000003f000b816b] 00:33:55 BackgroundTask named: "com.apple.metadata.mds.power"
Kernel Assertions: 0x4=USB
   id=503  level=255 0x4=USB creat=2023-09-09, 10:03 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.00100000 owner=USB3.0 Hub
   id=505  level=255 0x4=USB creat=2023-09-09, 10:03 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.00200000 owner=USB3.0 Hub
   id=506  level=255 0x4=USB creat=2023-09-09, 10:03 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.14400000 owner=USB 2.0 Hub [MTT]
   id=509  level=255 0x4=USB creat=2023-09-09, 10:03 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.14a00000 owner=Fast SSD
   id=510  level=255 0x4=USB creat=2023-09-09, 10:03 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.14900000 owner=Expansion Desk
   id=511  level=255 0x4=USB creat=2023-09-09, 10:04 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.14500000 owner=USB2.0 Hub
   id=512  level=255 0x4=USB creat=2023-09-09, 10:04 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.14b00000 owner=USB to PCIE Bridge
   id=514  level=255 0x4=USB creat=2023-09-09, 10:06 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.14200000 owner=USB2.0 Hub
   id=516  level=255 0x4=USB creat=2023-09-09, 10:07 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.14410000 owner=USB Advanced Audio Device
   id=517  level=255 0x4=USB creat=2023-09-09, 10:08 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.14470000 owner=USB 2.0 Hub
   id=519  level=255 0x4=USB creat=2023-09-09, 10:10 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.14420000 owner=Expansion Desk
   id=520  level=255 0x4=USB creat=2023-09-09, 09:55 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.14473000 owner=HD Pro Webcam C920
   id=521  level=255 0x4=USB creat=2023-09-09, 09:56 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.00110000 owner=USB3.0 Card Reader
   id=522  level=255 0x4=USB creat=2023-09-09, 09:56 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.00210000 owner=USB3.0 Card Reader
   id=523  level=255 0x4=USB creat=2023-09-09, 10:00 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.14240000 owner=USB 2.0 BILLBOARD
   id=524  level=255 0x4=USB creat=2023-09-09, 10:04 description=com.apple.usb.externaldevice.14540000 owner=USB 2.0 BILLBOARD
Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that if I do `sudo pmset repeat cancel` it does delete all the power events. This solves my issue for now. ‍♂️